# What parts of Hyperledger Fabric effect the scalability?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, blockchain, hyperledger-fabric

So from my understanding, kafka based ordering is what would be used in a production environment.

Within a Kafka based ordering environment we have:
Zookeeper nodes
Kafka nodes
Orderer Nodes
Peer Nodes

Within this environment which of these would effect scalability most or at all?

I am currently writing scripts to test a wide range of network architectures and I am hoping to understand how each component effects the performance through empirical evidence. If I am able to add some form of logic to my testing basis I should be able to understand my results a little better.

Comment: Have you made any progress ? I am not able to find much information on this .